# When testing the Fetch Cursor, not returning the correct value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently, I am running into a issue when I testing the fetch code. I declared a variable as @Positive_percentage as numeric value, It suppose to return a list of percentage, but when I PRINT the the Dynamic code, the @Positive_percentage returns NULL value for all the columns(This happens when triggering the SELECT @POSITIVE_PERCENTAGE,@COL_NAME). However, When I print the entire SQL and run somewhere else, it return the correct percentage and matching column name. Please someone provide some advice. Thanks

```
DECLARE @COL_NAME VARCHAR(100),@POSITIVE_PERCENTAGE NUMERIC(19,2),@SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE FINANCIAL_COL_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'STND_ENCOUNTER'
AND DATA_TYPE IN ('DECIMAL')

--AND COLUMN_NAME IN        
   ('TOTAL_PAYMENTS','BAD_DEBT_WRITEOFF','PATIENT_AMOUNT_PAID','PAYOR_AMOUNT_PAID','TOTAL_BALANCE_DUE')

 OPEN FINANCIAL_COL_CURSOR;

 FETCH NEXT FROM FINANCIAL_COL_CURSOR INTO @COL_NAME;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @SQL  = 
'SELECT @POSITIVE_PERCENTAGE = CASE WHEN COUNT('+@COL_NAME+') > 0 THEN CAST(CAST(SUM(CASE      WHEN CAST('+@COL_NAME+' AS FLOAT)>0 
                                                                  THEN 1 
                                                                  ELSE 0 END)AS      FLOAT)/CAST(COUNT('+@COL_NAME+') AS FLOAT)* 100 AS NUMERIC(19,2))
ELSE 100.00 END FROM STND_ENCOUNTER'

PRINT @SQL      

SELECT @POSITIVE_PERCENTAGE,@COL_NAME     --<-- this is where NULL value return



--IF @POSITIVE_PERCENTAGE <30.00
--  BEGIN
--      --UPDATE #temp
--      SET '+@COL_NAME+'  =  @COL_NAME * -1
--  END
PRINT @COL_NAME
FETCH NEXT FROM  FINANCIAL_COL_CURSOR INTO @COL_NAME;
END
CLOSE FINANCIAL_COL_CURSOR;
DEALLOCATE FINANCIAL_COL_CURSOR;
```

Comment: Instead of fixing the cursor maybe we can completely remove it and help you figure out a set based approach instead.

Comment: Also, you are creating dynamic sql but your variable @POSITIVE_PERCENTAGE is out of scope there. Even if it was in scope you don't execute your dynamic sql. Therefore your variable is never assigned a value so it will always be NULL.

Comment: Thanks Sean for the suggestions. I understand what you are saying. I will look into those issues. Meanwhile, If possible, could you guide me through on how to resolve this. much appreciated.

Comment: Well as I said the best thing to do here is to not use a cursor. Even if you need to stick with dynamic sql you can do this without a cursor. Here is where it gets challenging. I can't offer much help here because there are not enough details. Please post ddl (create table scripts) and sample data (insert statements). sqlfiddle.com can help with this. Once I have something to work with and an explanation of what you want I can help.

Comment: Thanks Sean for the suggestion. End up, I did not use cursor for this case. Instead, I just wrap the dynamic inside a while loop and it works fine. I have posted my solution below. Thanks again.

Comment: A well written cursor will almost always outperform a while loop. All you did was change one RBAR approach for another one that is slower.

Comment: Do you want some help to get rid of the loops or are you satisfied with a suboptimal solution?

Comment: If loop may causing the inefficiency, I would love to get rid of it. So far, those four columns as you see are the only thing I need to check. I personally don't see the reason need a loop but what happen if one day we need to check 50 columns or more. Anyway, please provide your insight on how to make sure this as a optional solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning any value to @POSITIVE_PERCENTAGE because your combination of dynamic / non-dynamic SQL is wrongly mixed.

It's this part:

```
SET @SQL  = 
'SELECT @POSITIVE_PERCENTAGE = CASE WHEN COUNT('+@COL_NAME+') > 0 THEN CAST(CAST(SUM(CASE      WHEN CAST('+@COL_NAME+' AS FLOAT)>0 
                                                                  THEN 1 
                                                                  ELSE 0 END)AS      FLOAT)/CAST(COUNT('+@COL_NAME+') AS FLOAT)* 100 AS NUMERIC(19,2))
ELSE 100.00 END FROM STND_ENCOUNTER'

PRINT @SQL      

SELECT @POSITIVE_PERCENTAGE,@COL_NAME
```

You assign value to @POSITIVE_PERCENTAGE inside the string @SQL, but you aren't **executing** the string. And if you did you'd get syntax error because in that context @POSITIVE_PERCENTAGE is not declared. (It's a different context)

You need to either wrap your dynamic SQL better for what you're trying to achieve (and execute it), or an even better approach would be to not do this with a cursor. (Cursors are usually not the go-to tool in SQL)

Comment: Thanks Allan for the valuable suggestion. I am accepting any suggestion to do this. The reason I use cursor is because I just want to simply loop through the column name and calculate the percentage then do a comparison with 30. If you don't think this is the way, please provide some better way to do or what do you think is the best way to modify to make it work. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide ddl for STND_ENCOUNTER?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for my situation

```
DECLARE @COL_NAME VARCHAR(100),@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),@POSITIVE_PERCENTAGE DECIMAL(19,2),
@INIT INT = (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
         WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'STND_ENCOUNTER'
         AND COLUMN_NAME IN           ('TOTAL_PAYMENTS','BAD_DEBT_WRITEOFF','PATIENT_AMOUNT_PAID','PAYOR_AMOUNT_PAID','TOTAL_BALANCE_DUE'))

WHILE (@INIT <> 0 )
BEGIN
            Select @COL_NAME = (    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM (
                                    SELECT COLUMN_NAME, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME DESC) AS RankByCOL
                                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
                                    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'STND_ENCOUNTER'
                                    AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('TOTAL_PAYMENTS','BAD_DEBT_WRITEOFF','PATIENT_AMOUNT_PAID','PAYOR_AMOUNT_PAID','TOTAL_BALANCE_DUE') 
                                    ) S
                                    where RankByCOL = @INIT)

SET @SQL = N'SELECT @POSITIVE_PERCENTAGE = CASE WHEN COUNT('+@COL_NAME+') > 0 THEN CAST(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN CAST('+@COL_NAME+' AS FLOAT)>0 
                                                                  THEN 1 
                                                                  ELSE 0 END)AS FLOAT)/CAST(COUNT('+@COL_NAME+') AS FLOAT)* 100 AS NUMERIC(19,2))
             ELSE 100.00 END FROM STND_ENCOUNTER'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@POSITIVE_PERCENTAGE DECIMAL(19,2) output', @POSITIVE_PERCENTAGE output           

            IF @POSITIVE_PERCENTAGE < 30.00
            BEGIN                   
                EXEC ('UPDATE DBO.STND_ENCOUNTER SET '+@COL_NAME+'= '+@COL_NAME+' * -1')
            END
 SET @INIT = @INIT - 1
END
```